# How to capitalize sentences when middle of the sentence is enclosed in parenthesis like (unix)?

Tags: python, file, capitalize

Suppose i have string like S="python (unix)" and i want to get following output : Python (Unix). Please suggest me.

How to solve above when senetence is to read from text file in Python?

Comment: Is the rule to just capitalize the first letter of every word?

Comment: we can use title() or capitalize()  in python.

Comment: >>> s="python (unix)"
>>> s.capitalize()
'Python (unix)'

Comment: In the above code only P became capital letter.i need to make First letter U also in capital letter from unix word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, using `re.sub` with a callback function which capitalizes each matching word:

```
S = "python (unix)"
out = re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda m: m.group().capitalize(), S)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
Python (Unix)
```

Comment: how to do same example when we read data from a text file consists of this type of scenario?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that.  Stack Overflow is not a forum, where the discussion keeps going after your original question has been answered.